# Downloading files with multiple connections make the browser crash

Tags: javascript

In my current project, a basic game in javascript with canvas, I've to download files : audio files.

To achieve this, I tried the first way : Downloading every file in succession. This made me crash my browser. I don't know why, but it did.

So then, I decided to download files in groups of 5 : multiples connections. And when one of them was downloaded, it starts a new download of an another file.
First, it didn't worked. I had to add a setTimeout of 250ms before downloading a new file.

It works, but here's my problem : It takes so long.
When I set the number of multiples downloads to 4, it works with no problem. But with 5, it makes my browser going slowly, and sometimes, the tab crashes.
And the worst is that, when downloading theses groups of 5 files, it makes the canvas rendering slower (from 60fps to 2fps), making animations slower too.

So, how to make theses downloads faster and lagless ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by you first tried "downloading every file in succession." ?

Comment: For each url in an array, I send the XMLHttpRequest. Without waiting something, so every request was made at the same time.

Comment: Could you show how you are doing these requests ? Your browser should not crash, whatsoever, if it does, file a bug to their bug reports board. (Also check taht it s effectively the downloading part that do crash, and not what you are doing with the data after => remove every other code and audit only the downloading part.

Comment: There are multiples types of files. The text files and binary files like audio. After the end of each request, it converts it in base64 for saving it in a string.
Is there a better way to store binary files in a variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i've found a way to do it.
I used the Audio() element, and waiting for the "canplaythrough" event.